# mod_python on CentOS under httpd and hsphere

Tags: apache, mod-python, centos5

I have asked our hosting provider to add mod_python to our httpd server.  The server appears to be in an hsphere cluster and they appear to use yum to administer it.  He is reporting some dependencies missing and I do't quite understand how that could have come about.

versions (this is as much as I have been given):
CentOS 5
apache - 2 (but he's not sure about the exact version)
mod_python - 3.3.1
numpy - 1.1.1
scipy - 0.6.0
yum - 3.2.8
hsphere - 3.1 patch 1

The error he is reporting is as follows:

```
yum install mod_python
...
Package mod_python.i386 0:3.2.8-3.1 set to be updated
Processing Dependency: httpd >- 2.0.40 for package: mod_python
Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_python
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.0.40 is needed by package mod_python
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by package mod_python
```

Not being a UNIX admin I only have a naive guess about this, but the message would seem to suggest that there is a version mismatch between httpd and mod_python rather than the dependencies being missing completely.

So my question is, what should I ask/tell the Administrator to do?

Is there something obviously wrong with the combination of components above?

Answer (score 1):

We have mod_python 3.3 running on Apache 2.2 on a CentOS (forgot the version). All we did is download the tar.gz (from http://httpd.apache.org/modules/python-download.cgi) , extract it...

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
$ ./make
$ su
$ make install
```

Everything works fine. We couldn't use yum so everything is built from source.
My suggestion would be to try to build from source.

Comment: do note that apxs location will change as time goes on. To be safe, make sure you do `yum provides apxs`, install the missing packages and change the --with-apxs directory with the directory specified.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction would be to `yum update apache` (or just a `yum update`).

Then try the `yum install mod_python`.

Answer (score 0):

also getting same issue

--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_python.i386 0:3.2.8-3.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: httpd >= 2.0.40 for package: mod_python
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_python
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.0.40 is needed by package mod_python
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by package mod_python